# How to find and remove data records associated with an inactive approval process?

Tags: approval-process

I have a custom field that is referenced by an Approval process, long since deactivated. However when I try to delete the Approval process, I get:

> Cannot Modify Active/Once Active Approval Process Definition
>   Once an approval process has been activated, you cannot add or remove steps. Please create a new approval process from this one for modification. You may only delete an approval process that has no data records associated with it.

I did find some records by using Setup > Mass Transfer Approval Requests where I reassigned a bunch of approval requests to myself and then approved them (this is a test environment).

But it did not change the result - I still get the same error when trying to delete the approval process. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not due to the fact that the records were not approved, but the fact that records still exist in your environment that went through the process. Since it stores the history of the approval (and therefore the steps of the approval), it would require you to delete the records to sever that relationship. I believe the only way to resolve this would be to delete any record that has entered this approval process at one point or another.

[Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_considerations.htm&language=en_US)

> Active approval processes can't be deleted. Before deleting an approval process, make sure it is inactive and that no records have been submitted for approval. If any records have been submitted, delete them and remove them from the Recycle Bin.

---

Please [note](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009CWpIAM), you must empty the recycle bin to allow this to happen.

Answer (score -4):

When you are getting issue that
Cannot Modify Active/Once Active Approval Process Definition
Once an approval process has been activated, you cannot add or remove steps. Please create a new approval process from this one for modification. You may only delete an approval process that has no data records associated with it.?

Ans :  First you need to check items to approve data. If the is existed then make them clear as your need. Still you are getting the same issue then check the recycle bin also. If you have items to approve data in recycle bin then also we can't delete the approval processes. All before Approval processes should be inactivated before deleting

Comment: This appears to be largely the same as the existing answer from nearly 8 years ago, just with slightly different (and less clear, in my opinion) wording/presentation.